# Getting control over pushing screen globally from background process

Tags: java, blackberry

Hello all i want to control on pushing the screen globally from background application. currently i made a **Screen which is extending MainScreen.** I want to show this screen globally. I am using
`pushGlobalScreen(Screen to push, int priority, flag);` its working if there is two screen it showing one after other. But what i want to do actually is. I want to close the first screen then i want to show the next screen and so on . So how to achieve this.

Here i am explaining it more clearly

I am explaining the whole scenario I am checking in the database for the time if current time matches with the alarm time then it pushes the screen let suppose there is more than one alarm is saved for the same time.

```
while (Checking into database for time){
if (databasetime == current time ) {// let suppose there is more than 
                                    //one alarm save for the same time
    synchronized (getEventLock()) {// This will call one after other but i want to first

        UiEngine ui = Ui.getUiEngine();

        ui.pushGlobalScreen(new AlarmScreen() , 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);//  
                      //Here i want to stop. I want user to close the screen then
                      // i want to push again the screen. As we do in
                      // PushModalScreen(Screen) How can i block 
                     //pushGlobalScreen(new AlarmScreen() , 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
         }

   }

}
```

I think my requirement is clear now.  is it??

Comment: What I have understand is you don't want to push more than 1 `AlarmScreen` instance on display stack, is it?

Comment: yes you are right i want to push the 2nd screen after closing the first one do you have any suggestion for that

Comment: I have posted a code snippet, check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue but in different way. The way i have choosed is, I am storing all the id in the table and checking if there is any id in the table i am pushing only one screen. And before closing it i am checking if there is more id in the table just `updating the Contents of the Screen`. Now it is working just as the way i wanted, and if there is no more data i am just closing the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Check follwing code snippet for removing an `AlarmScreen` instance from display stack before pushing a new `AlarmScreen` instance.

```java
net.rim.device.api.ui.Screen currentScreen = Ui.getUiEngine().getActiveScreen();

// pop previously pushed AlarmScreen
if (currentScreen instanceof AlarmScreen) {
    try {
        Ui.getUiEngine().popScreen(currentScreen);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iaexc) {
        // If your screen is not on the stack.
    } catch (Exception exc) {           
    }
}

// push new AlarmScreen
synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
    Ui.getUiEngine().pushGlobalScreen(new AlarmScreen() , 1, UiEngine.GLOBAL_QUEUE);
}
```

---

Following application (`UiApplication`) uses a queue of `AlarmScreen`. Upon an active `AlarmScreen` removal from display stack, it pushes another `AlarmScreen` from waiting queue into display stack.

```
package mypackage;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class MyApp extends UiApplication implements CloseEventListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new MyApp()).enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    private AlarmScreen []queue;
    private int MAX = 10;
    private int head = 0;

    public MyApp() {
        // initialize queue 
        queue = new AlarmScreen[MAX];
        head = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
            queue[i] = new AlarmScreen(this, "Screen no. " + i);
        }

        // push first screen on display
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(queue[head ++]);
    }

    public void screenClosed() {
        if (head < MAX) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(queue[head ++]);
        }
    }
}

interface CloseEventListener {
    public void screenClosed();
}

class AlarmScreen extends MainScreen {
    private CloseEventListener listener;

    public AlarmScreen(CloseEventListener listener, String title) {
        setTitle(title);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public boolean onClose() {
        try {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    close();
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
        }
        // push a new screen from waiting queue
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.screenClosed();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: actually i dont want to do it by this way i want user to close the screen then i want to push the new AlarmScreen(); ie, the code pushGlobalScreen should not run twice if there is one screen is present in display stack. It sud wait untill there is no screen currently on the Stack. Thanks for your snippet of code.

Comment: Then you can maintain a queue, which will holds all the `AlarmScreen` instance. And when an user close an active `AlarmScreen`, just push the first element of the queue (if not empty) to display. If you need help on the implementation then I can give you hints.

Comment: yeah ofcourse if you can provide some help it will be good :)

Comment: okk  will do that if get success i will accept it and thanks for the code snippet let me check how it goes :) will accept your answer if it work. For now upvote for your try thanks

Comment: one thing how can i implement it in my application. As you know i am in background application.

Comment: Please first check the code and try to get the idea I wanted to explain. If you understand that, then you can use the idea as you want. You only have to change the screen pushing utility for an `Application` instance.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java can you come here in this chat room